# How to get width of the Button in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to show `EditText` and `Button` in one line. But the size of the button is the fixed to some pixels. I wanted to get the width of `Button` programatically so that i can adjust width of `EditText` on changing the orientation to vertical or horizontal my XML file is as follows

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/middleLayout" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
<EditText 
    android:layout_height="50px" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/searchBox"
    android:layout_marginTop="2px"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:hint="Enter Zip Code, City &amp; State"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="20px" 
    android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_marginTop="3px"
    android:text="Search"
    />  
</LinearLayout>
```

I am calculating it by following code.

```
searchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBox);   
searchbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);  
int searchIconWidth = searchbutton.getWidth();
 searchBox.setWidth(getting_screen_width() -  searchIconWidth );
```

for calculating screen width I have used following

```
private int getting_screen_width() 
    { 
    DisplayMetrics dm = null;
    dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    String width = ""+dm.widthPixels ;
    dm = null;
       return Integer.parseInt(width);
    }
```

But when I run above code than `EditText` takes full width & Search button is not shown. What can be the problem in getting the Button width in Pixels.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think if the width is a problem. set a same value to both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the same code in `onResume()` as when this gets call you will get all the components placed already and can be rearranged.

just a small change in code due to deprecation.

Change from

`android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

to

`android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would want to use a different layout for landscape. Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Basically you can have a second layout for landscape creating a new folder in the `/res/` path called `layout-land`. Place there your new layout with the same name and Android will take care of the rest.

Comment: you are right, but my problem is, when I am trying to print the width of button, it shows me 0 in Logcat. so the EditText is taking full screen. I wondering about width given in xml to that button is treated as 0px in program.

Comment: Where are you placing that Log line?

Comment: I'm printing value of  searchIconWidth variable. I have don that in my debugging part not posted here.

Log.d("ButtonWidth",""+searchIconWidth);

But you can place after this line

int searchIconWidth = searchbutton.getWidth();

Comment: @Ashay: Sorry, I am willing to know if you place it `onCreate()`, `onStart()`. I guess you should place it `onStart()`.

Comment: I am placing it in onCreate()

Comment: @Ashay: Plz try placing it `onStart()` just to be sure.

Comment: @Macarse: I did. But, still no change. You have gone through my code can you tell me is there any logical mistake while calculating the width of button & width of screen ? or setting the width dynamically to the EditText ?

Comment: The view isn't drawn yet on oncreate or onstart. You have to check for the width AFTER the view is drawn.